# In React/Redux, how to post data following JSON API structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I created a form in React and I have a API that has a JSON API structure, i.e. with the response inside the `data: []` property. And I'm using `Axios` and `redux-thunk` to fetch the data.

The data coming from the form `state` has this structure:

```
{
  title: '',
  phone: '',
  email: '',
  description: ''
}
```

How do I convert it so it follows the JSON API convention, using `axios`, `redux-thunk`, `action` and `reducer`:

```
{
  data: [{
    title: '',
    phone: '',
    email: '',
    description: ''
  }]
}
```

This is where I'm stuck:

**Reducer**:

```
export default function roleReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.SAVE_ROLE_SUCCESS:
      return [
        ...state,
        Object.assign({}, action.role)
      ];

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Actions**:

```
export function saveRoleSuccess(role) {
  return {
    type: types.SAVE_ROLE_SUCCESS,
    role,
  };
}
```

**Thunk**:

```
export function saveRole(role) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return axios.post(apiUrl, role)
      .then(savedRole => {
        console.log('Role: ', savedRole);
        dispatch(saveRoleSuccess(savedRole));
        console.log('Get state: ', getState());
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('Oops! Role not saved.', error);
        }
      });
  };
}
```

I'm not sure where and what to do to format a new data into the JSON API structure.

Comment: This question is very unclear.  Are you asking how to put an object into an array? `(obj) { return { data: [obj] } }`??

Comment: @gravityplanx, yes the question is how can I add my data into the `data` array from JSON API?

Comment: What do you mean "from JSON API"?  The silly little function in my previous comment creates the simple object with a `data: []` property... is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I think here:

```
return axios.post( apiUrl )
```

You're not actually sending any data. I reckon you want to do:

```
const dataToPost = { data: [ role ] }; //wrap the role in an array and an object
return axios.post( apiUrl, dataToPost ); //send the data
```

Comment: Thanks for your for your response, I've updated my question by adding the the data in the 2nd parameter of `axios.post()`. Does your answer follow the JSON API structure when I send the data?

Comment: I think so - give it a try!

Comment: thanks for your answers. It makes sense. Sorry I wasn't sure and I'm not familiar with axios and thunk. But thanks again.